# Django как задать фильтр для ManyToMany?

Tags: django, django-filter

У меня есть модель для тегов и постов :

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                            null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag_name


class Post(models.Model):
.......
.......
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name="blog_tag",
                            blank=True)
```

Я написал вьюху :

```
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,
                             status="published",
                             publish__year=year,
                             publish__month=month,
                             publish__day=day,
                             slug=post)
    post_tags = Tag.objects.all().filter(tag=post.tag) это не работает, 
    ка правильно задать фильтр чтобы в темплейт вывести теги
    для данного поста ?
    return render(request, "blog/post_detail.html",
                  {"post": post, "tags": tags, "post_tags": post_tags})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем вы передаёте теги в контекст отдельной переменной? Достаточно передать `post` и в шаблоне получить теги из него

```
{% for tag in post.tag.all %}
    {{ tag }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Блин, работает. Спасибо. Отдельная переменная нужна для вывода всех тегов в темплейт и возможности сортировки по ним.